# Using parametrize for multiple arguments in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, parametrize

There is such a function:

```
def underscore_concat(*args):
    return "_".join(filter(None, ([*args]))).upper()
```

How to correctly pass multiple parameters using pytest.mark.parametrize?

Something like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, result", [(["underscore", "concat", "test"], "UNDERSCORE_CONCAT_TEST")])
def test_underscore_concat(a, result):
    assert underscore_concat(**a) == result
```

Comment: Your code is working and looks alright, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found assert. Must be underscore_concat("underscore", "concat", "test") == result

Comment: You have to unpack lists with a single `*`, double `**` is for dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, result", [(["underscore", "concat", "test"], "UNDERSCORE_CONCAT_TEST")])
def test_underscore_concat(a, result):
    assert underscore_concat(*a) == result
```